# How to retrieve TEXT values from mysql database using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am using MySQL to populate data in my application.
In my database I have a text field comment.
I  want to retrieve that value.

How is it that I am using rs.getString(ColumnIndex) but it can not retrieve the text values from it?

I am currently doing so:

```
rsIntelligenceOverTime.getString(7).toString().trim()
```

Anybody Please help.

Comment: The obvious questions in the absence of any details are: is the result set initialized correctly? Is 7 definitely the correct column index?

Comment: Fixed some spelling and formatting. Removed a redundant help request.